# What is the difference between CPU_PER_CALL and CPU_PER_SESSION?

Tags: oracle, database-administration

Im confused about the difference between CPU_PER_CALL and CPU_PER_SESSION, so can any one tell me the difference.

Answer (score 1):

`CPU_PER_CALL` limits the amount of CPU that a single SQL statement can consume.  `CPU_PER_SESSION` limits the total amount of CPU that all the SQL statements that are run in a single session can consume.

In general, a session will involve the execution of many different SQL statements.  So if you're going to set both, you'd generally want the session limit to be orders of magnitude larger than the call limit.

Comment: Thank You so much Mr. Justin Cave

Answer (score 0):

Froms [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_6010.htm)

> CPU_PER_SESSION  Specify the CPU time limit for a session, expressed
>   in hundredth of seconds.
>
> CPU_PER_CALL  Specify the CPU time limit for a call (a parse, execute,
>   or fetch), expressed in hundredths of seconds.

`SESSION` as name says, is calculated from user connection checkout till checkin.

Whereas `CALL`, is every SQL call to the DBMS.

So, when these values for violated for any user activity(querying), the dbms would abort the operation throwing an exception. These are used to avoid unwanted overhead to the database.

Comment: Just quoting the documentation is not an answer. He said he was confused by that, he needs further clarification.

Comment: Man.. i was typing the answer. I understand wwhat you intend to say. The statement from DOCS is always goingto be better than we type. thats why I used this. using iPad, I am unable to type and format so fast.

Comment: Thank You so much Maheswaran Ravisankar

Answer (score 0):

Besides the allready described difference ( check "cpu usage per call" vs "check cpu usage per session" ), as far as I know:

- Violating  CPU_PER_CALL  limit just creates an ORA-Error ( = Terminates Execution )
- Violating  CPU_PER_SESSION  limit creates an ORA-Error and logs you of ( = Terminates Execution and Session)